# Countable unions in a semi-ring are disjoint unions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I suck and I can't even do the  first exercise in Klenke's Probability Theory. Could really use some help.

Anyway let $\mathcal{A}\subset 2^\Omega$ be a semiring on $\Omega$. This is to say that

i) $\emptyset\in \mathcal{A}$.

ii) If $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B\in \mathcal{A}$.

iii) If $A,B\in \mathcal{A}$, then there exist $A_1,...,A_n$ such that $A\setminus B=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^n A_j$, where we use $\bigsqcup$ to denote a mutually disjoint union.

We would like to show that any countable union $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ can be written as a countable disjoint union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$. My first thought was to define sets $B^{i,j}_k\in \mathcal{A}$ where
$$A_i\setminus A_j=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^{N_{i,j}}B^{i,j}_k.$$
It is not clear at all what to do with these sets though because as we vary $i,j$ we do not have pairwise disjoint sets. My main issue is that there is seemingly no way to cover $A_i\setminus\bigcup_{j\neq i}A_j$ because $\bigcup_{j\neq i}A_j$ is not even in the semiring.

The construction to turn a countable union to a countable disjoint union in a $\sigma$-algebra is pretty trivial, so maybe I could mimic that, but you have to union together sets to get an increasing sequence of sets, which does not seem to interact well with the semiring structure.

Edit: I think I figured it out. You do want to mimic the $\sigma$-algebra version. Put $F_1=A_1$. Now define $F_{j+1}=A_{j+1}\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^jA_i$. Then some basic set algebra shows $$F_{j+1}=\bigcap_{i=1}^j A_{j+1}\setminus A_i=\bigcap_{i=1}^j \bigsqcup_{k_i=1}^{N_i}B^{i,j}_{k_i}=\bigcup_{k_1=1}^{N_1}...\bigcup_{k_j=1}^{N_j}B^{1,j}_{k_1}\cap...\cap B^{j,j}_{k_j}.$$
Then $$\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^\infty F_j=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^\infty\left(\bigsqcup_{k_1=1}^{N_1}...\bigsqcup_{k_j=1}^{N_j}(B^{1,j}_{k_1}\cap...\cap B^{j,j}_{k_j})\right)$$